# How to use OneHotEncoder and LabelEncoder together?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have dataset composed by:

- binary data (example: 'yes', 'no'),
- multiple nominal data (example: 'father', 'mother', 'other'),
- binary numerical data (0,1),
- multiple numerical data (example: 1,2,3,4,5).

Target: define a function to encode the columns with the nominal data.
How would I like it? Encode in the same function some columns with `OneHotEncoder()` and other columns as `LabelEncoder()`. 
In the specific, I want only the nominal (feature_1:'father', 'mother','other'; 
feature_2: 'home', school 'reputation', 'course' preference or 'other')  data encoded as OneHot and the rest of the features label encoded.

I did this code but it use only LabelEncoder; I would like to implement it with OneHotEncoder (only for nominal data) if  possible.

```
def encoder(df):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    for c in df.columns:
        if df.dtypes[c] == object:
          df[c] = le.fit_transform(df[c].astype(str))
    
    return df
encoder(stud)


stud.head()
```

Comment: You can use scikit-learn's [Column transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html)

Comment: Yes, it can be used in my case but I would have to manually select the columns.  If I wanted to automatically select them based on their nature within a function, would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select_dtypes` method in pandas along with Column transformer.

```
cate_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=["category"]).columns.tolist()
bin_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=["str", "int"]).columns.tolist()
encoders = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cate_cols),
    (OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=np.nan), bin_cols),
    remainder='passthrough')
```